Regex pattern to return value that has no prefix of Amount:
I'm trying to write a regex where it would only pick up the 135.00 as a result and not the 216.35.  It always has a prefix of "Amount: "
$135.00

Amount: 216.35

This is what I have so far:
(?<Amount>[^$]\d+.\d+)

Thank you!

What about Test: $135.00 or Test: 135.00 ?

I actually used Anthony's response below but removed the ^ and it worked.

You can try this :
^\$([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)$

^ : start of line
\$ : match the character $, if you want it optional add a ? just after
[0-9]+ : any digit multiple times
\.? : optional dot (you need to add the antislash as it is a reserved character)
[0-9]* : any digit multiple times again but 0 times allowed so $1 works
$ : end of line
() to capture group
Here you can test your regexp : https://regex101.com/r/amyUHG/3
